# Getting a count of an outcome which match a date

Tags: if-statement

I know that this will be a really simple answer but I cannot ask the right question on Google to get the answer I want.

What I want to know is how to get Excel to look in column B to look for a particular date, then every time it finds a match to that date count what is in column H. There are only 2 responses in column H "Dealt With" and "Passed Back" I've tried the following but of course it hasn't worked

=IF(B<>O3,COUNTIF(H2:H2000,"Dealt With"),"")

I think I am close so if anyone could just tell me how to correct this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further soul searching I found what it was. In-case anyone new like me wants to know, what I wanted was to use countifs.

=COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$404,$L$3,$B$2:$B$404,O3)

Countifs added both the matching date and the response. I then just made two separate columns to count them.